# Parse.com set text strikethrough on click

Tags: android, android-listview, parse-platform

I have a parse.com application and I am wanting to have it when I click on a list item it strikes the text out and when I click it again it returns the text to normal. Any idea on how I can do this? Thanks!

```
public class AgendaActivity extends Activity {

    //First Call ArrayList
    private ArrayList<String> assignments;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        assignments = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, assignments);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        agendaList();
    }

   //Query List
    public void agendaList(){
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Agenda");
        query.whereEqualTo("userId", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            //Show up in list
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> parseObjects, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    // If there are results, update the list of posts
                    // and notify the adapter
                    assignments.clear();
                    //Gets all data from parse
                    for (ParseObject post : parseObjects) {
                        assignments.add(post.getString("name") + "\n" + "Date Due: " +
                                post.getString("dueDate") + "\n" + "Class: " + post.getString("class"));

                    }

                    ((ArrayAdapter<String>)getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    //Error Logging
                    Log.d("Post retrieval", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this!

tv is the textView.

```
tv.setPaintFlags(tv.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG); //this strikes through the text
```

Also, to unstrike use this,

```
tv.setPaintFlags( tv.getPaintFlags() & (~ Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG));
```

Use this in your getView method of the adapter class.

Also, a suggestion, you could explore [ParseQueryAdapter](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseQueryAdapter.html) to list the objects fetched from Parse.